# Audit the Update columns of a MERGE statement as rows in a different table

Tags: .net, sql-server, t-sql, merge, audit

**I am trying to achieve the the following**

- MERGE a TARGET and SOURCE table.
- Use the output clause to audit the changes.

**I am able to do the following using CASE Statements:**

- Audit inserts and deletes easily.

**I am getting the inserts and deletes into the following format:**

```
| Action   | Record | ChangedFrom | ChangedTo |  
|----------|--------|-------------|-----------|  
| Inserted | 1      | NULL        | 1         |  
| Deleted  | 2      | 2           | NULL      |
```

**What I am not able to get:**

```
| Action  | Record | ChangedFrom        | ChangedTo         |  
|---------|--------|--------------------|-------------------|  
| UPDATED | 1      | ColA_Content_Before| ColA_Content_After|
```

The Merge statement outputs the changed values as Columns per row.
I need to change these pairs of columns to rows so each changed column for a record/row becomes an entry in the audit table.
Also here for examples sake I have used 3 columns, in practice I need it to work when I dont know what the number of columns is.

***Target Table***

```
| Id | ColA | ColB   | ColC   |
|----|------|--------|--------|
| 1  | Orig | Orig_B | Orig_C |
```

***Source Table***

```
| Id | ColA       | ColB       | ColC   |
|----|------------|------------|--------|
| 1  | Modified_A | Modified_B | Orig_C |
```

***MERGE RESULT***

```
| Id | ColA | ColB   | ColC   | Id | ColA      | ColB       | ColC |
|---:|------|--------|--------|----|-----------|------------|------|
| 1  | Orig | Orig_B | Orig_C | 1  | Modifed_A | Modified_C |      |
```

***I need these cols as rows***

```
|  Action | Record | ChangedFrom | ChangedTo  |
|--------:|--------|-------------|------------|
| Updated | 1      | Orig        | Modified_A |
| Updated | 1      | Orig_B      | MOdified_B |
```

**The methods I have tried:**

- Use the MERGE inside a proc to execute batch statements
- Here I have tried to use a cursor to iterate through rows and then insert the cols inside a case statement.
- Use dynamic sql and pivot the table.

However have not succeded.

Any pointers?

***Code to replicate***

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test_Source]
(
   Id int NOT NULL,
   ColA VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   ColB VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   ColC VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   ColD VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   [UDate] [DATETIME] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY];
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test_Target]
(
   Id int NOT NULL,
   ColA VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   ColB VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   ColC VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   ColD VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   [UDate] [DATETIME] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY];
GO


---Insert some test values
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test_Source]
(
   Id,ColA,ColB,ColC,ColD,UDate
)
VALUES
(
  1,'ColA','ColB','ColC','ColD',GETDATE()
);

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test_Target]
(
   Id,ColA,ColB,ColC,ColD,UDate
)
VALUES
(
  1,'ColA_After','ColB_After','ColC_After','ColD_After',GETDATE()
);

CREATE PROCEDURE MERGE_TEST 
As
BEGIN
        DECLARE @MERGERESULTS TABLE 
        (
         [Action] nvarchar(50),
         Id_After int ,
         ColA_After nvarchar(50),
         ColB_After nvarchar(50),
         ColC_After nvarchar(50),
         ColD_After nvarchar(50),
         UDate_After nvarchar(50),
         Id_Before int,
         ColA_Before nvarchar(50),
         ColB_Before nvarchar(50),
         ColC_Before nvarchar(50),
         ColD_Before nvarchar(50),
         UDate_Before nvarchar(50)
        );

        DECLARE @AUDITRESULTS TABLE 
        (
         [Action] nvarchar(50),
         Id_After int ,
         ChangedFrom nvarchar(50),
         ChangedTo nvarchar(50)      
         );

        DECLARE
         @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
         @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

        MERGE Test_Target as T
        USING Test_Source as S
        ON T.Id = S.Id
        WHEN MATCHED AND
        T.ColA <> S.ColA OR
        T.ColB <> S.ColB OR
        T.ColC <> S.ColC OR
        T.ColD <> S.ColD OR
        T.UDate <> S.UDate 
        THEN UPDATE SET
        T.ColA = S.ColA ,
        T.ColB = S.ColB ,
        T.ColC = S.ColC ,
        T.ColD = S.ColD ,
        T.UDate = S.UDate 
        WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
        THEN INSERT 
        (Id,ColA,ColB,ColC,ColD,UDate)
         VALUES
        (S.Id,S.ColA,S.ColB,S.ColC,S.ColD,S.UDate)
         WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE 
        THEN DELETE 
        OUTPUT $action,Inserted.*,Deleted.* into @MERGERESULTS ;

        select * from @MERGERESULTS;

        select * into #mytemp from @MERGERESULTS

        -- Dynamic sql to pivot table
            select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(ColA_After) 
                        from @MERGERESULTS
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                 ,1,1,'')

            set @query = 'Select * from #mytemp
                    pivot 
                    (
                        max(Id_After)
                        for ColA_After in (' + @cols + ')
                    ) p '

            select  @Cols as 'Columns';

            execute(@query)

     -- Dynamic sql to pivot Table

-- Trying cursor and row count (incomplete)
            --declare @Id int

            --set rowcount 0
            --select 
            --t.Action ,
            --CASE WHEN (t.ColA_After <> t.ColA_Before)
            --  THEN t.ColA_After  
            --END,
            --CASE WHEN (t.ColA_After <> t.ColA_Before)
            --  THEN t.ColA_Before  
            --END,

            --CASE WHEN (t.ColB_After <> t.ColB_Before)
            --  THEN t.ColB_After  
            --END,
            --CASE WHEN (t.ColB_After <> t.ColB_Before)
            --  THEN t.ColB_Before  
            --END,

            --CASE WHEN (t.ColC_After <> t.ColC_Before)
            --  THEN t.ColC_After  
            --END,
            --CASE WHEN (t.ColC_After <> t.ColC_Before)
            --  THEN t.ColC_Before 
            --END,

            --CASE WHEN (t.ColD_After <> t.ColD_Before)
            --  THEN t.ColD_After  
            --END,
            --CASE WHEN (t.ColD_After <> t.ColD_Before)
            --  THEN t.ColD_Before  
            --END
            --from #mytemp t
            --inner join #mytemp t1
            --on t.Id_After = t1.Id_Before
            --where 
            --t.ColA_After <> t1.ColA_Before OR
            --t.ColB_After <> t1.ColB_Before OR
            --t.ColC_After <> t1.ColC_Before OR
            --t.ColD_After <> t1.ColD_Before 
            --set rowcount 1

            --select @Id = Id_After from #mytemp

            --while @@rowcount <> 0
            --begin
            --  set rowcount 0
            --  (select * from #mytemp where Id_After = @Id)

            --  delete #mytemp where au_id = @au_id

            --  set rowcount 1
            --  select @au_id = au_id from #mytemp
            --end
            --set rowcount 0

END

EXEC MERGE_TEST
```

This seems like it is going on a tangent

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved the above by using unpivot

not sure if this is the best way, but gets the work done.

**My solution:**

- Use a Procedure and select the MERGE results into TABLE variable, with columns suffixed _Before and _After.
- Audit the Inserts and Updates using a where condition.
- Use UNPIVOT to audit the updates.
- The pivot col values can be used to get the updated column name.
- The UNPIVOT needs all cols to be of same datatype, so can CAST/CONVERT them, I have just stored all as nvarchars() when selecting into.

***CREATE AUDIT SCRIPT***

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Audit](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ChangedFrom] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [ChangedTo] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Action] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [ChangedDate] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [Column] [nvarchar](100) NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Audit] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

**CREATE PROCEDURE SCRIPT**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MERGE_AUDIT
As
BEGIN
        --Temporary TABLE variable to store the MERGE results
        DECLARE @MERGERESULTS TABLE 
        (
         [Action] nvarchar(50),
         Id_After nvarchar(50),
         ColA_After nvarchar(50),
         ColB_After nvarchar(50),
         ColC_After nvarchar(50),
         ColD_After nvarchar(50),
         UDate_After nvarchar(50),
         Id_Before nvarchar(50),
         ColA_Before nvarchar(50),
         ColB_Before nvarchar(50),
         ColC_Before nvarchar(50),
         ColD_Before nvarchar(50),
         UDate_Before nvarchar(50)
        );

        MERGE Test_Target as T
        USING Test_Source as S
        ON T.Id = S.Id
        WHEN MATCHED AND
        T.ColA <> S.ColA OR
        T.ColB <> S.ColB OR
        T.ColC <> S.ColC OR
        T.ColD <> S.ColD OR
        T.UDate <> S.UDate 
        THEN UPDATE SET
        T.ColA = S.ColA ,
        T.ColB = S.ColB ,
        T.ColC = S.ColC ,
        T.ColD = S.ColD ,
        T.UDate = S.UDate 
        WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
        THEN INSERT 
        (Id,ColA,ColB,ColC,ColD,UDate)
         VALUES
        (S.Id,S.ColA,S.ColB,S.ColC,S.ColD,S.UDate)
         WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE 
        THEN DELETE 
        OUTPUT $action,Inserted.*,Deleted.* into @MERGERESULTS ;

        -- Audit the Inserts
        insert into [Audit]
        (
            ChangedFrom,
            ChangedTo,
            Action,
            ChangedDate
        )
        select 
            Id_Before,
            Id_After,
            [Action],
            GETDATE()
        from @MERGERESULTS where [Action] = 'INSERT' ;

        --Audit the DELETES
        insert into [Audit]
        (
            ChangedFrom,
            ChangedTo,
            Action,
            ChangedDate
        )
        select 
            Id_Before,
            Id_After,
            [Action],
            GETDATE()
        from @MERGERESULTS where [Action] = 'DELETE' ;

        --unpivot to audit the UPDATES,
        --USING REPLACE to remove the AFTER suffix when getting the column name
        -- When storing the MERGE results in the TABLE variable having all columns as NVARCHAR is needed as to UNPIVOT the datataypes are needed to be same
        insert into [Audit]
        (
            ChangedFrom,
            ChangedTo,
            Action,
            ChangedDate,
            [Column]
        )
        select * from (select 
            ChangedFrom,
            ChangedTo,
            [Action],
            GETDATE() as ChangedDate,
            REPLACE(p1col, '_After', '')  as [Column]
            from 
            (select 
            *
            from @MERGERESULTS
            UNPIVOT
            (
                   ChangedFrom
                   FOR pcol IN (ColA_Before,ColB_Before,ColC_Before,ColD_Before)
            ) AS P
            UNPIVOT
            (
                ChangedTo 
                For p1col IN (ColA_After,ColB_After,ColC_After,ColD_After )
            ) p1) as a
            where 
            a.pcol = 'ColA_Before' and a.p1col = 'ColA_After' OR
            a.pcol = 'ColB_Before' and a.p1col = 'ColB_After' OR
            a.pcol = 'ColC_Before' and a.p1col = 'ColC_After' OR
            a.pcol = 'ColD_Before' and a.p1col = 'ColD_After') as o -- this where condition is needed to get only relevant results, else we will get all the cols as it is a cross join
        where o.ChangedFrom <> o.ChangedTo;
END
```

**RESULT on EXECUTION**

```
EXEC MERGE_AUDIT
```

[image: PROC RESULT]